# GIT branch not merging

Tags: git

I have three branches:

```
*branch_a
main
master
```

tied to a remote repository. i am currently on the branch_a branch, which has differences from the remote main branch: origin/main. that is, the remote origin/main has a file named 'file.txt' with the letter 'A' as the only character, whereas my local branch, branch_a, has the same file, 'file.tx' with the letter 'B' as the only character. I can see these differences while checked out in the branch_a; using:

```
git diff origin/main
```

however, when i try to merge theses changes, that is merge from the remote origin/main, i am getting:

```
Already up to date.
```

I'm not sure how come the changes are not showing up and merging from the remote origin/main to my local branch, branch_a.

Comment: It probably means that the revision where you change content is a revision on the local branch _past_ the last revision in origin/main.... so, you can't _pull_ anything from that branch as you are up to date with its content... or rather, history (you have everything in that branch already in your branch).

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving enough information to know *the* reason, but it's easy to give *a* reason. Let's say you did this:

1. On `main`, create the file *file.txt* with content A.
2. Add and commit and push.
3. Create branch `branch_a` and switch to it.
4. Edit the file *file.txt* to have content B.
5. Add and commit.

Now you will see the same phenomena you just described. `origin/main` and `branch_a` show a diff for *file.txt*, but you cannot merge `origin/main` into `branch_a`. This is because `branch_a` is *ahead* of `origin/main`. It *is* `origin/main` plus an additional commit, and that's *all* it is. There is nothing to merge, because `branch_a` already "has" all the same commit(s) that `origin/main` has.

But now do this:

6. Switch back to `main`.
7. Create another file, add it, commit, and push.
8. Switch back to `branch_a` and try the merge again.

Now you will be able to merge because there is something to *do*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying :

```sh
git add file.txt
git commit -m "your comment here"
git push
```